# Likelihood of being admitted to a top 10 CS PhD program?

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions, graduate-school, computer-science, stem

**== Deleted ==**

Deleted because this question is closed and not relevant to the community-at-large.

Answer (score 4):

I'm currently in a Computer Science PhD program in Canada, and from my point of view you have a few misconceptions.

- Getting into a top school is not necessary to be a successful researcher. Your advisor will have far greater impact on your research output than the choice of school. "Top" schools often have famous professors, who will take on many graduate students and have little time for them individually.
- Your demographic does not matter, and it may in fact strengthen your application, if schools have equity programs.
- If you manage to get into a grad school, your performance in undergrad isn't necessarily a good indicator of your research abilities. Memorization and exams are  big in undergrad, but hold little weight in grad school. Writing ability, communication skills, and the ability to perform self directed research are far more important.

I would find a school that has a few professors you'd be interested in working with and apply. The worst that happens is you don't get in.